# No module named 'scipy.stats', but it's installed

Tags: python, scipy, archlinux

On Arch Linux I got this error No module named 'scipy.stats'

```
> python3 ./ddqn.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 93,
> in <module>
>     backend_module = importlib.import_module(_BACKEND)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked  
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in
> exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/keras/backend.py", line 31,
> in <module>
>     import scipy.stats ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats'
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./ddqn.py", line 19, in
> <module>
>     from keras.models import Sequential   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>     from . import utils   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in
> <module>
>     from . import conv_utils   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9,
> in <module>
>     from .. import backend as K   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line
> 108, in <module>
>     raise ValueError('Unable to import backend : ' + str(_BACKEND)) ValueError: Unable to import backend : plaidml.keras.backend
```

But this module installed:

```
> ls /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/
> __init__.py               _multivariate.py                        mstats.py
> __pycache__               _rvs_sampling.py                        mstats_basic.py
> _binned_statistic.py      _stats.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  mstats_extras.py
> _constants.py             _stats_mstats_common.py                 mvn.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> _continuous_distns.py     _tukeylambda_stats.py                   setup.py
> _discrete_distns.py       contingency.py                          statlib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> _distn_infrastructure.py  distributions.py                        stats.py
> _distr_params.py          kde.py                                  tests
> _hypotests.py             morestats.py                            vonmises.py
```

I tried installing it in two different ways:

> pip3 install scipy

and

> sudo pacman -S python-scipy

How can I force it to find module in this place?(/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/)

Comment: What happen if you try to execute `import scipy` and `import scipy.stats` from python console?

Comment: impot scipy works well. But import scipy.stats gets : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats'

Comment: which scipy version?

Comment: I think scipy is 1.3.0 version.

Comment: Ok. The `ModuleNotFoundError` can be raised also if module initialization fails. Run the command `python3.7 -v -c "import scipy.stats" 2> log.txt` then try to parse log.txt file or add this information to your question.  This is verbose version of python.

Comment: I parse log and realise that it search for stats in /home/vic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats,  but stats is not there I remove scipy dir from there and all works.

Comment: Update your question with information about soulution to help other users with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the location to look at with `sys.path.insert` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)).

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <your-location>)
```

and it should find it!

Answer (score 0):

I parse log (produced by command `python3.7 -v -c "import scipy.stats" 2> log.txt`) and find that it search for stats in $HOME/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats, but stats is not there I remove scipy dir from there and all works. If it installed by pip  with --user flag it installs to $HOME/.local/python3.7/site-packages/